# how do I create alias or variables in css file

Tags: css

I am having list of css files and every css file has different image location code written like url(../_images/headerImages.jpg), now I am placing my images to some other domain therefore I want to create a variable like var domainPath = http://sitename.com so that at every url(../) I could write something like url(domainPath+ '/images/headerImages.jpg').

Example

```
var DOMAIN_PATH = http://www.mysite.com;

#header {background: url(DOMAIN_PATH/_images/headerimage.jpg)no-repeat; }
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use variables in plain CSS. I suggest using a CSS preprocessor which is a language that compiled to CSS. [SASS](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://sass-lang.com/&ei=NEdZUdmiM6iOiAed8oCoDQ&usg=AFQjCNGj26Uvw2Xaq_ZQbByTuIQsbFtzjA&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aGc) is fantastic and you can do what you ask like so:

```
$domainpath: url(http://www.mysite.com/_images/bg-header-noodletools-express.jpg);

#header {background: $domainpath no-repeat; }
```

Another alternative is [LESS](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://lesscss.org/&ei=QEdZUaW7L6mkiAfT9YGwBA&usg=AFQjCNF-GHR66GftFm9aMGmUFpVKsYvD7A&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aGc).

Comment: Ok. Thanks Daniel. I will try using SASS/Less.

Comment: Can I do this without using SASS/Less, because It seems a little complicated for me?

Comment: No, variables in CSS is something that will be available in the future.  If you want it now, you need a CSS Preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://ishadeed.com/article/css-vars-101/ and others, it is possible to use variables in CSS now.

You can do:

```
:root {
  --domainpath: url(http://www.yourdomain.com/_images/bg-header-noodletools-express.jpg);
}

#header {
  background: var(--domainpath) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CSS is not dynamic but you can do something like this:

1. store your URLs in the: root selector Which represents the root element and is identical to the selector `html`, except that its specificity is higher.
2. use the URL variable

```css
:root {
    /* define your variables here */
  --url1: url(http://sitename.com/image1);
  --url2: url(http://sitename.com/image2);
}
.img {
  background-image: var(--url2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Full source code: [here](https://codepen.io/sanusi_hassan/pen/zYaNXeX?editors=0110)

Comment: code [updated].